# How to create & update data as array saved in individual rows

Tags: arrays, laravel, string, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm into a problem where i need to insert data into the database table as an array and i was able to save it individually in the database, image & codes attached below

[image]

Here's how my input code looks like  `create.blade.php`

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="extras_name[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="extras_price[]">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="extras_name[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="extras_price[]">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Store function in the controller

```
   public function store(Request $request, CustomProduct $customProduct)
{

    $data = $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required',
        'brand'=>'required',
        'price'=>'required',
    ]);

    $customProduct = $customProduct->create($data);

    $data = $request->all();

    foreach ($data['extras_name'] as $index => $extras) {
        CustomProductExtra::create([
            'name' => $data['extras_name'][$index],
            'price' => $data['extras_price'][$index],
            'custom_product_id'=> $customProduct->id,
        ]);
    }

   return redirect('custom-product');
}
```

This is how its saved in the database

[image]

When i try to update the data the last data will be duplicated in both the rows

**Edit view**

[image]

It saves the last input in both the rows like this
[image]

Update function in the controller

```
 public function update(Request $request, CustomProduct $customProduct)
{
    $data = $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'required',
        'brand'=>'required',
        'price'=>'required',
    ]);

    $customProduct = $customProduct->update($data);

  $data = $request->all();

  foreach ($data['extras_name'] as $index => $extras) {
    CustomProductExtra::where('custom_product_id',23)->update([
        'name' => $data['extras_name'][$index],
        'price' => $data['extras_price'][$index],
    ]);
}
    return redirect('custom-product');
}
```

It saves the last input in both the rows in the database,

**NOTE : The issue is on the Update**

Can someone please help me out with this issue

Comment: So your issue is in update. Am I right ?

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Yes

Comment: is my answer working ?

Comment: @NipunTharuksha No it didn't

Comment: ok what was the issue then

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as it should. What you are doing here is updating all the records via for each. So when your loop ends its updating with last data index.Instead of that you need to loop your custom extra products with index. But this is not best method. Better if you could pass the id with extra values too. You can do it likes below

```
foreach (CustomProductExtra::where('custom_product_id',23)->get() as $index => $custom){
 $custom->update([$data['extras_name'][$index],$data['extras_price'][$index]]);
}
```